# Scrollable bottom sheet in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Can a bottomsheet be made scrollable? For example it opens initially upto a particular height and scrolls up as the content is scrolled. If yes, please help!

Answer (score 3):

The [DraggableScrollableSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html) is here for that purpose.

This widget can be dragged along the vertical axis between its `minChildSize`, which defaults to 0.25 and `maxChildSize`, which defaults to 1.0.

You can use any Scrollable widget as child of DraggableScrollableSheet.

See the official [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hgw819mL_78) from Flutter team.

Comment: You can not use NestedScrollView.